# How can I parse this one?

Tags: java, xml, sax, xstream

Used XStream lib, but no children XML was difficult to parse in Java.

Wanting to parse Simple XML File but don't know how to do it.

Is there any effective way to parse ?

> ***< xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ? > < error > <
>   ![CDATA[ Hello ]] > < /error >***

thanks in advance.

Comment: Please teach why the child tag of the error tag cannot be prepared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve the CDATA using sax using characters() callback. Here is the [example](http://www.coderanch.com/t/127987/XML/read-cdata-sax-parser)

Comment: Pangea, Sincerely Thanks! AWESOME extreme example. That's what I am finding.